# Why python absolute import does not work?

Tags: python

I am trying to use absolute imports in my script. There are 2 variants.
Before I had used in main.py:

```
from helper import time_measurement
from logger import logger
```

This example worked perfectly.

Then I tried to use absolute import e.g.:

```
from porous_calc.helper import time_measurement
from porous_calc.logger import logger
```

And this mistake turned out:

```
*PS C:\Users\Anvar> & C:/Users/Anvar/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe c:/Users/Anvar/Desktop/SW2/gitProject/4dtomo/porous_calc/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Anvar/Desktop/SW2/gitProject/4dtomo/porous_calc/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import porous_calc.anisotropic_volume_gen as avg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'porous_calc'
PS C:\Users\Anvar>*
```

All files (main.py, helper.py, logger.py) are located in the same folder porous_calc. Why the second type of imports does not work?
Program has been run from VS Code command line.

Comment: Did you check `PYTHONPATH` or your IDE's path config.

Comment: You're not using `porous_calc` as a package. Rather, Python recognizes both `logger` and `help` as being their own distinct packages and not submodules of `prorous_cal`. Normally, you would need to import the these modules using  `from . import module`. How precisely are you running your code?

Comment: `porous_calc` is one level up from your `main.py`, so something like this: `from .. import porous_calc`, this will work if you have a proper `__init__.py` setup correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is no such thing as an "absolute import" in python3.  Everything is relative to the current location.  The typical way of doing something like this is:

```
from .helper import time_measurement
from .logger import logger
```